# Method main is never used locally! Why?

Tags: java, class, methods, return, program-entry-point

I am taking a class in java and have some problems with this code: It says that classOne and the main String are never used locally. Why?

```
public class classA {

    private static class classOne{


        protected static int a; 
        protected static String b; 

        public Haustier (int x, String y){          
            a= x; b = y; 
        }


        void print (int a, String b){
            System.out.println("this is a result "+a+" . This is also a  "+b+" result.");   
        }


        public static void main(String[] args){

            classOne H1 = new classOne(4, "Fluffy");
            classOne H2 = new classOne(3, "Lessi");


            H1.print(a, b);
            H2.print(a, b);

            }
    }

    }
```

The question in a nutshell: Implement a class, a constuructor, a method and print the result via System.out.println.

(of cause there are more details, but this would be the short version.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because you can't embed a `main` method in an inner class. Move `main()` to the outer class.

Comment: i wonder what was the error, ones you compile it

Answer (score 1):

I am having to make some guesses here: you wrote this code in an attempt to solve the problem of which you give a brief description?

I am going to guess that you did not know that, although it is legal to put one class inside another class, that it is somewhat advanced and not something you are liable to need for an introductory assignment.

Your `ClassA` is sufficient to solve the problem, there is no need to declare another class at all.  Dispense with `ClassOne` altogether.  You will need a main method in `ClassA`; that is where execution will start once you start the resulting java program.  Separately, you can write a constructor for `ClassA`, and the main method of that class can invoke it to create an instance of the `ClassA` class.  You could also implement a method for `ClassA` besides main; you can just declare it `public void printValue()` or something like that, and then call it using the variable holding the `ClassA` instance that you created.  Those two lines would look something like this:

```
ClassA classAInstance = new ClassA(); // here you are using your constructor
classAInstance.printValue();          // here you are calling your method.
```

See if you can put the rest of it together yourself.  Good luck